# Transfer SQL Server Logins from 2008 to 2016 hashed password not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash

I am migrating a number of databases from SQL Server 2008 to SQL 2016. I have used the script from https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/918992/how-to-transfer-logins-and-passwords-between-instances-of-sql-server to transfer logins. The procedure generates something like this to run on 2016:

-- Login: TEST1

```
CREATE LOGIN [TEST1] WITH PASSWORD = 0x0100DBC2C8D9113D8A7393CBD4FB042997DA1A00B54BBABFE0BA HASHED, SID = 0xE926DF241772C047BA6D1BE874C1F8E1, DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master], CHECK_POLICY = ON, CHECK_EXPIRATION = ON
```

but login doesn't work on SQL2016. I'm assuming this is because of the hash used is different between the two instances. SQL2008 usesd SHA-1 but SQL2016 uses SHA-2 (or maybe something else?)

How can I solve this issue without having to create new passwords in 2016. Can I specify the type of hash algorithm that 2016 uses? To match that used in 2008?

Comment: They changed the algorithm in 2012 and upwards, but it should be backwards compatible. What do you mean the login doesn't work? Do you have an error message? Do you have the original password of the SQL login that you are migrating?

Comment: I thought it would be backwards compatible. I do have the login and have tried to login to SSMS but I get login error 18456. I can login in to the original database with same details

Comment: Please check all the error details to this [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-2016) page. Maybe it can help you find out the real reason of the login failure.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that new SQL server only allowed Windows auth. Changed to mixed mode and worked.